# Add rows together

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rows

I have one table with some rows and lot of columns (about 50)
- I don't want to list all the column names, co I use a while loop to go through the table and a foreach command to find the column names and values.
Now I would like to add these two rows into one row (where id is 1) and sum the values together...

```
id | col 1 | col 2 | ...
 1    30      21
 1    11      16
 2    75      0
```

It should look like this

```
id | col1 | col2 | ...
 1    41     37
 2    75      0
```

This is what I have...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`='1'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        if($key != 'id') {
            //the sum code...?
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me? Thank you a lot...

Comment: You may have legitimate reasons for constructing a table with 50 columns, but (too) often it's a symptom of poor (i.e. non-normalized) design.

Comment: @mike621 please accept an answer. it will help your career on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

just sum the results in mysql.. databases are made to handle things like this so it'll be a faster solution than doing it just in php.

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    SUM(col1), 
    SUM(col2) 
FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code which indicates you're using mysql I'm going to give you a mysql solution (which can easily be ported to most RDBMS).  What you're looking for can easily be accomplished with [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). Follow the link to read about all the aggregate functions mysql has.

`SELECT id, SUM(col1), SUM(col2) FROM table GROUP BY id;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: See the Explanation as comments:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`='1'");
//Initially Set all the columns as zero.
$col1 = 0; $col2 = 0; 
//Etc.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        if($key != 'id') {
            $$key += $val;
            //Like: $col1 += 30;
        }
    }
}

//Now All the variables are ready added:
//Like:  $col1 = 41;
//Like:  $col2 = 37;

//Use them However you like:
//To update:

//1. First Delete both rows:

$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id`='1'");

//2. Insert


$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`id`,`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ('1','{$col1}','{$col2}') ");
//And so on



?>
```

Comment: this is a much slower solution than doing it in mysql. you should specify that in the answer

Comment: @JohnRuddell Yeah, But the Asker wanted this way. I think. However, internally MySQL also does something similar.

Comment: regardless you should clarify that and sometimes... people want something a certain way when they shouldn't do it that way ;)

Comment: @JohnRuddell I hope he will know by now. Thanks for your comments

Comment: Sure thing. still +1 for another way to do it :)